# Draw bottom navigation bar behind the system navbar in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, android-jetpack-compose-material3, compose-multiplatform

In compose multiplatform, how can we draw the bottom navigation bar behind the system navigation bar? I'm trying to make use of the WindowInsets, but not getting any clue.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? show your code please